# How can you calculate the likelihood of getting a set of stats or better when rolling 4d6 drop lowest?

Tags: statistics, anydice

If I have a given set of character stats from rolling with "4d6, drop lowest", how can I calculate the probability of getting that specific result, or better values for each of them?

For example, one of the players in my campaign got 15, 15, 15, 14, 13, 13.  In particular, any one of the values is lower than the highest expected value from rolling 4d6, drop lowest (16), but the average is very high. (The order of rolling does not matter, you can sort them highest to lowest or assign them to stats freely afterwards).

How likely is it to get that array or better (in the sense for each die separately, to get a result as high, or higher)?

I'd like to know this die by die, because typically, it is better to have some high dice and some low dice than a higher average of middling dice or just a higher total of points overall. (For example, the player here plays a wizard, and while  high Dex and Con etc. are all nice, he really would have liked a 16 so he could get to 18 Int out of the gate).

How would a formula or anydice program look like, where I can just plug in the rolled numbers, and find out how likely it was to get them? (Anydice is my preferred tool, but other tools are OK too).

Comment: Does the order matter? Note that 16 is not the value with the highest probability.

Comment: The odds of getting that roll "or better" may need some clarification. Better how? Would trading a 15 and a 13 for two 14s be better? How about trading them for a 16 and a 12? (I'd generally prefer the latter, but some players might not.) There's probably a way to get the odds of the exact roll, but the "better" rolls need to be better defined before anyone can compute their odds.

Comment: Order of rolling does not matter, you can sort them highest to lowest afterwards. Better in the sense this result or higher in each case, so 15 or higher for the hightest die, 14 or higher for the 4th highest die in the example. Let me know if there is a better way to think about "how likely is it to get a result as good or better ". Because of the issues @Blckknght points out, and because often having a few very high and a few very low dice is preferable to a higher total from or average of middling dice I'd go with better for each specific die.

Comment: I believe that you have to clarify the question: title and body ask two different things.

Comment: @Eddymage Is that better? The title neccesarily must be a bit shorter than the full explanation

Comment: "any one of the values is lower than the highest expected value from rolling 4d6, drop lowest (16)" - not so. The expected value is 12.24, the median is 13 and the mode is 13.

Comment: @DaleM What I mean is that as your highest value in 4d6 drop lowest, you can expect to get a 16. None of the values here is a 16, so any one of them is lower than that. I guess this is the difficulty about framing the question, how do you determine which roster is "better" when just a higher sum of values is often worse, if they are about evenly distributed than a roster with a few high, and a few low ones.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

AnyDice can calculate this pretty easily.  All we need to do is write a custom sequence comparison function, since AnyDice compares sequences lexicographically* by default.  Here's the code:

```
function: are all elements in A:s at least as good as in B:s {
  loop P over {1..#B} {
    if P@A < P@B { result: 0 }
  }
  result: 1
}

TARGET: [sort {15, 15, 15, 14, 13, 13}]
STAT_ROLL: [highest 3 of 4d6]

output [are all elements in (#TARGET)d(STAT_ROLL) at least as good as in TARGET]
  named "1 = rolled at least as well as target"
```

FWIW, the chance of rolling each stat at least as well as in your example target array is [apparently](https://anydice.com/program/32dde) **about 0.76%**.

---

Ps. Note that this comparison function may or may not be a good definition of rolling "better than" a target stat array.  In particular, note that it considers e.g. (18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 12) *not* to be "as good as" (15, 15, 15, 14, 13, 13), since the last stat is lower!  In practice, if given a choice, you'd *probably* still rather take the former array than the latter.

Also note that, according to this comparison method, *neither* of the two arrays above is "at least as good as" the other, since both contain a stat that's lower than the corresponding stat in the other array.  In fact, this is quite common, so you shouldn't be surprised that the chance of rolling better than even quite average arrays *on all stats* can be quite low.  [For example](https://anydice.com/program/32ddf), the probability of rolling *at least 12 on every stat* is only about 5.49%!

For an alternative comparison method, you might want to consider [comparing stat arrays by their point buy cost](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/185250/struggling-with-rolling-for-stats-probability-calculation/185292#185292) instead.  Luckily I already have some AnyDice code for that (see the linked answer), so I could [quickly check](https://anydice.com/program/32de1/at_least) that e.g. the D&D 5e point buy cost of your target array is 44 points, whereas a standard 6 stat array rolled with 4d6 drop lowest has a **13.62% chance** of being worth at least that many points.

---

*) This fancy term means that it first compares the first elements of the sequences, and only those are equal, moves on to compare the second elements, and so on.  This is exactly the same way that we sort words in alphabetical order by comparing their letters one at a time.

Comment: Thank you for an - as usual - wonderful answer, especially for pointing out that using aggregate point buy values may be a more useful approach to defining a good array.

Answer (score 6):

[A similar question was previously asked on mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4379856/probability-that-one-set-of-dice-rolls-is-greater-than-or-equal-to-a-given-set/4401448#4401448). You can use the same script, just with a fixed set of scores for one side.

```
from icepool import d, MultisetEvaluator, Order

single_ability = d(6).highest(4, 3)

class StrictlyBetter(MultisetEvaluator):
    def next_state(self, state, outcome, a, b):
        advantage, a_had_one_up, b_had_one_up = state or (0, False, False)
        advantage += a - b
        if advantage > 0:
            a_had_one_up = True
        if advantage < 0:
            b_had_one_up = True
        return advantage, a_had_one_up, b_had_one_up
        
    def final_outcome(self, final_state):
        _, a_had_one_up, b_had_one_up = final_state
        if a_had_one_up and not b_had_one_up:
            return 'a strictly better'
        elif b_had_one_up and not a_had_one_up:
            return 'b strictly better'
        elif not (a_had_one_up or b_had_one_up):
            return 'exactly the same'
        else:
            return 'mixed result'
    
    def order(self):
        return Order.Descending
    
evaluator = StrictlyBetter()
output(evaluator.evaluate([15, 15, 15, 14, 13, 13], single_ability.pool(6)),
       'fixed vs. variable')
output(evaluator.evaluate(single_ability.pool(6), single_ability.pool(6)),
       'variable vs. variable')
```

Result:

**fixed vs. variable**

Die with denominator 4738381338321616896

| Outcome | Quantity | Probability |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a strictly better | 2034207168637998592 | 42.930423% |
| b strictly better | 35336500568217600 | 0.745750% |
| exactly the same | 638472231782400 | 0.013474% |
| mixed result | 2668199196883618304 | 56.310352% |

**variable vs. variable**

Die with denominator 22452257707354557240087211123792674816

| Outcome | Quantity | Probability |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a strictly better | 4696617436843743365666704597889926627 | 20.918241% |
| b strictly better | 4696617436843743365666704597889926627 | 20.918241% |
| exactly the same | 5069150678806043464398031458429484 | 0.022577% |
| mixed result | 13053953682988264465289403896554392078 | 58.140940% |

Given two random players, there's more than a 40% chance that one will roll strictly better than the other!

[You can run this in your browser here.](https://highdiceroller.github.io/icepool/apps/icecup.html?c=GYJw9gtgBAlgxgUwA5jAG1hFIAuUAmANFALICuaOMAzgjgKIBuAhmmczmCMQPIj4IQAKCHUYAOwDmaBAH1mAIxhoYOAJ5QAvAQAUANgCUAOgAWMSSYTUcOgCzEAzAZFw0zatSgBlHCHg40NQAhOhxBHXJKGjomVnZOEAMALiEoNIIEYChxBAAPHFlrDgQdWjRgYiKw4jAyHDhIBGJmYgVk1PTO5nwWcRxmSSaoZlkTbtkwHNkyJFbR8cm5Ga0oKoQoLigdAAZiADFWWn3DhGdOrp7mPoH1gGptZigAWigFDvPYLO7e-sGoAD4oNsUh8PiMxvgJlNltoACogMgId7nGBfS7XP4AHiBINBnQU80hi2mSBW8MRyM6IDoZBA4mG6N+Q3BC2hs1ehKhSyQlPSyIEWWAElYEzqDQgJTKFSgQvEIrW7TxsmanOJMzmEK5JJWsvl-TCvLSqOGqrZw3E+GyYDwBM1aqQuLxaWpOFp9IA5I9rH44AENApQoJ3YaoAgVFlbazuebLeJrSa7WzHU6XW6oO6FKtfP5Aq9AyBg3iw8a43gdCyiWbNpHK9zFU7nTS6em8sxfbmcJZVswJYXQWHaMm8anm+6IDBcghLdTqBQcH20vzMht+OEpfWPiP6XwBCAjAARKyIC0SSTIoQIFhsDibbQ+H1+kI4MIgHTOWo4JB1HSXuI3ve-teYQ6AA2gAjAArMQkHQVBUBgfY8EONBDgALqVKeMjyEoKjqEYKDoPoBgGIQhrukKk6Wow1BGFALB+IoMjuu+dRfjYgHxFwRgccUpSYXIijKKoaj4agaBERhUhYYJuEiQR4mGCRZH0TAjHrNRtEqWpzFCEAA)

This uses my [Icepool Python probability package](https://github.com/HighDiceRoller/icepool). The `MultisetEvaluator` uses dynamic programming to efficiently compute solutions to dice pool problems; `next_state` sees how many 18s were rolled by each side, then how many 17s, then 16s, and so forth. If you'd like to know more about the algorithm, you can [read my paper here](https://github.com/HighDiceRoller/icepool/blob/main/papers/icepool_preprint.pdf).

You may also be interested in my [ability score rolling method calculator](https://highdiceroller.github.io/icepool/apps/ability_scores.html), which will graph sorted ability scores and point buy equivalents for a variety of configurable methods.

#### Related questions

[Probability for completely unfair stats.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/110671/probability-for-completely-unfair-stats-when-rolling-ability-scores-using-4d6-dr) That question investigates the more extreme case of comparing the lowest high score in a group to the highest low score in the group. In other words, where this question asks whether the lucky player can pair up their scores with the unlucky player so that they meet or exceed the unlucky player in all six, that question asks whether the lucky player does so regardless of assignment.

[The "snake draft".](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/120334/how-can-i-model-this-party-draft-pool-ability-score-generation-method-in-anydi) Personally I dislike the pick order effects this introduces.

Comment: Thank you so much. I +1ed, and again picked HDR's answer to accept, because a formulation in AnyDice saves me from having to learn yet another system for playing around with the results.  Thank you for providing an easy to access way to try out Icepool however, which if I understand it right, it has superior implementation properties compared to AnyDice.  Your ability score calculator is also pretty nifty and easy to use. I've downloaded your paper to learn a bit more about this.